# How to make the upper and lower limits of a between clause dependent on the groups defined by the group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

```
X(a,b,c,d)
Y(a,b,d0,d1)
```

I am trying to do this:

```
SELECT a, b, MAX(c) FROM X WHERE X.d BETWEEN Y.d0 AND Y.d1 GROUP BY a, b;
```

Y has only one record per group a,b

I am not sure how to introduce `Y` into this statement so I can get different `d0` and `d1` values from table `Y` for every `a,b`. Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to run before you can walk - an ill advised strategy

Comment: @Ramski - are you sure there are records to return? Try a specific case of a, b and check manually what values you have in the Y table and how many in the X table. Check that the data types are compatible, and that X.d, Y.d0 and Y.d1 are not NULL.  Write your query specifically for that and check it gives you the result you expect.

Comment: I tried using constants in place of Y.d0 and Y.d1 and it returns results. Y is a temporary table, and it is originally derived from X, which is not temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT Y.a, Y.b, Max(X.c) FROM Y LEFT JOIN X ON (Y.a = X.a) AND (Y.b = X.b) WHERE (((X.d) >=  Y.d0 AND (X.d) <= Y.d1)) GROUP BY Y.a, Y.b;

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN Y to X like this:

```sql
SELECT a, b, MAX(c) FROM X INNER JOIN Y ON(Y.a=X.a AND Y.b=X.b) WHERE X.d BETWEEN Y.d0 AND Y.d1 GROUP BY a, b;
```

In a more complex query where you may not want to add in another join you could use subselects to get the values like this:

```sql
SELECT a, b, MAX(c) FROM X WHERE X.d BETWEEN (SELECT d0 FROM Y WHERE Y.a=X.a AND Y.b=X.b) AND (SELECT d1 FROM Y WHERE Y.a=X.a AND Y.b=X.b) GROUP BY a, b;
```